# Proper way to pass pointers into many subroutines

Tags: fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I'm not a very good programmer and I'm just trying to interface with a model that provides data as pointers. These pointers are passed down through several subroutines before data is written to them. I'm not sure how to do this so that I avoid memory leaks.

Let's say I have an array pointer `A` that is passed to several subroutines before being written to, how do I handle the declarations, allocations, and deallocations?

```
module data

implicit none
contains 

subroutine s1(a)
real, pointer, intent(out) :: a(5,5)

call s2(a)
end subroutine s1

subroutine s2(a)
real, pointer, intent(out) :: a(5,5)
integer :: i 

do i = 1,5 
  a(:,i) = 5.0
end do
end subroutine s2
end module data

Program test
use data, only : s1, s2
real, pointer, dimension(:,:) :: A => NULL()
allocate(A(5,5))
call s1(A)
write(*,*) A
deallocate(A)
end Program test
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but if you have a problem with your code it's likely related to the `intent(out)` attribute of those pointers.  See, for example, [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29737367).  Or the so-called _explicit shape_ nature (which conflicts with being pointer).

Comment: You need to specify the dimension only once. In the subroutines you should declare a as:
`real, pointer, dimension(:,:), intent(out) :: a`.
After `deallocate (A)`, if you no longer need the pointer, you can `nullify(A)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that your code is not Fortran 90. The `intent` attribute for dummy (formal) arguments that are pointers was introduced in Fortran 2003.

The `intent` refers to the association status of the pointer, not to its target. Also, if the argument is a derived type with
pointer components, the `intent` applies to the type object itself, not the targets of the pointers. That is, if, for example, `intent(in)` is used, the data area that the pointer is targeted at can be modified:

```
module MyType_mod

  implicit none
  private

  type, public :: MyType
     integer, pointer :: ptr(:)
   contains
     procedure :: sub => my_type_sub
  end type MyType

contains

  subroutine my_type_sub(self)
    ! Dummy argument
    class(MyType), intent(in) :: self

    ! The following is perfectly legal,
    ! even though intent(in) was specified
    self%ptr = 42

  end subroutine my_type_sub

end module MyType_mod

program main

  use MyType_mod, only: &
       MyType

  implicit none

  type(MyType) :: foo
  integer      :: alloc_stat

  allocate( integer :: foo%ptr(100), stat=alloc_stat )
  call foo%sub()

end program main
```

Even though not required, in a case such as the previous example, it is better to state `intent(inout)` to indicate to the reader that modification of data is taking place.

On another note, you may find this answer useful [Fortran subroutine returning wrong values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38140951/fortran-subroutine-returning-wrong-values/38154225#38154225)

Comment: The statement "I'm not a very good programmer" seems contrary to wanting to use pointers. And even the really good programmers often avoid pointers for a variety of reasons.It is hard to see why you want to use pointers from the code provided. I would reconsider whether you need pointers or not, even though the use of pointers is an interesting question.