# Why is this value `save`d between calls in this Fortran function?

Tags: fortran, intel-oneapi

I'm maintaining a legacy Fortran codebase that (to my eye) relies on undefined behavior. There's a module defined like this

```
module the_module

private :: baz

contains

integer function foo(bar)
    type(my_type) :: bar ! my_type is defined elsewhere, and is a *large* data structure
    if (.not.baz(bar)) then
        foo = 0
        return
    end if
    ! ...    
end function

logical function baz(bar)
    type(my_type) :: bar
    type(my_type) :: previous_bar
    if (bar%field /= previous_bar%field) goto 10
    ! ...
10  previous_bar = bar
end function

end module the_module
```

I understand that if a variable is initialized **at declaration**, it implies the `save` attribute which retains the value between calls. The `baz` function does **not** do that, nor does it explicitly have the `save` attribute. Why, then, has the code been able to rely on `previous_bar` containing the previous value passed into the function? The first time it's called, `previous_bar` seems to have a zeroed out structure (`character` variables are spaces, numeric values are all 0).

My suspicion is that since `my_type` is a large data structure, it's probably being stored statically in memory, and the author just got lucky that the compiler chose that. My other guess is something to do with the fact that `baz` is `private` (almost no other functions in this code base are `private`). I'm using the Intel oneAPI legacy IFORT compiler.

Comment: FORTRAN before 1990 did not support recursion, and local variables in subprograms were often allocated statically (and as you observe zero-initialized), though except for COMMON this was never _required_, and some systems used overlays which clobbered locals. It is still _allowed_ unless you specify RECURSIVE. Some compilers now have options; I don't know about your specific compiler but likely someone will.

Comment: @steve I can't imagine what in the definition of `mytype` could make this code to have a predictable behavior... Maybe if it had a `final` bound procedure that would save some data somewhere AND if it was initialized with a constructor that would restore the values, but there's no call to a constructor in the code.

Comment: Possibly just worth restating that having a variable undefined also means that you can get [the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29737699/3157076) as though it remained defined

Comment: @steve Yes, the `previous_bar%field` component is maybe initialized in the type definition, but always with the same value. And still, the updated value is supposed to be lost upon exit of the routine. It's possible that this code has a defined behavior depending on what is not shown, but likely not the intended one.

Comment: @steve The definition of `my_type` in the real code is an (obscenely) large structure with many fields, including fixed-length arrays and fields of other defined structures. Nothing has a default value, no constructors are called, and no procedures are bound. I know of this constructor syntax `my_variable = my_type(positional, args)`, but none of the code base uses it. Everything's declare-and-assign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely right, this code relies on the fact that `previous_bar` is statically allocated by the compiler, which is allowed but not required by the standard. Furthermore, even if this variable was `save`d, the standard does not require the compilers to initialize it. `baz` being private doesn't make any difference here. So, depending on the compiler, this code may work, or not work.

Note that with (coming) compilers that will conform to the F2023 standard, this code is even guaranteed to fail, as this revision will make all subroutines `recursive` by default, thus requiring the compilers to NOT statically allocate the non-saved variables.

Comment: Fortran 2018 makes `recursive` advisory only.

Comment: It could also just be caused by reusing the stack frame that did not get overwritten. There is neither a guarantee of a fail with a compiler that trats it as recursive, nor a clear evidence that it is indeed allocated statically here.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Maybe it could, but it would work even more "by chance"...